# Return key when value in range

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a large data set where values are non-overlapping ranges that are sorted in increasing order. There are holes between ranges and keys (type is long) can be assigned to multiple ranges:

```
[100,300] K1
[310,400] K1
[401,600] K2
[650,1000] K3
...
```

I need to find a key for a given value. If value doesn't belong to any range, I should return 0.

My approach was to build

```
NavigableMap<Long, Range> map = new TreeMap<>();
```

and then

```
map.put(K1, new Range(100,300);
...
```

That results in a quite large map that is sorted by keys. This is not what I want since I would prefer to have a map that is sorted by range values so that I can easily conduct binary search. My problem is that I don't know how to use this map to find key for a given value. For example, value 101 should return K1, 500 should return K2, 301 should return 0. Is there any way to achieve what I want using NavigableMap or am I using the wrong approach?

Comment: Is it possible the ranges can be intersected with each other?

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: Are third-party libraries allowed?  This is almost exactly what Guava's [`RangeMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/RangeMap.html) provides.

Comment: Yes. Actually, they are preferred as long as the lookup is fast (there are around 40K entries)

Comment: @LouisWasserman in this case it will be better to use `RangeSet`, because ranges are disconnected.

Comment: @KenBekov it doesn't matter.  The OP wants to map ranges to values, and that's exactly what `RangeMap` does.  (I wrote them both, for what it's worth.)

Comment: Is this necessary to use `Map`? Why not just implement `Comparable` interface in `Range` class, and do binary search on sorted `List`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have stated the ranges cannot overlap but may have gaps, you should use a `NavigableMap<Range,Long>` with a `Range` representation that uses only the lower bound of the range for the `hashCode` and `equals` implementations.

Note that I have reversed the order of the generic types in the `NavigableMap` from what you show in your code sample.

To search for a value you want the largest entry (i.e. the entry with the largest lower bound) that is less than the search key.

Conversely, if you used the upper bound in the `Range` object, you'd want the smallest entry larger than the search key.

After you find the appropriate `Map` entry you have to double check that the key value is actually within range, due to the possible gaps.

Comment: The Range you are referring to: is it a custom defined Range (such as in my case) or some built-in functionality?

Comment: A custom-defined `Range` class that you write, and override `hashCode()` and `equals()` to be based on either the lower or upper bound only.  That works ONLY because ranges cannot overlap.  If you need to allow range overlaps then you have a completely different data structure requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit dummy but might work.

Create a type having `min-max-assign (e.g. [100,300, K1])` values. Then sort them based on their `min` values.

If you search for a `min` value, then binary search will return the position of it (say x), otherwise, it will return `-index_to_be_inserted - 1`. Then you can check if your value is in the range.

For example,

```
[100,300] K1
[310,400] K1
[401,600] K2
[650,1000] K3
```

Your arraylist will be 100 (300, 'K1'), 310 (400, 'K1'), 401 (600, 'K2'), 650 (1000, 'K3').

If you search for 101 to 309, binary search result will be -1(`x`). Check the max value in the index `-x-1 = -(-1)-1 = 0`. 
If you searched `101` then `101<300` and you will return `K1`, if you searched for `301`, you will return `0`.

I don't claim this is the best way but it is a way that works with `O(log_n)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe, `Map` is not needed at all. You can just implement `Comparable` interface in `Range` class, and do the binary search in sorted list:

```
public class Range implements Comparable<Range>{

    private int start;
    private int end;

    public Range(int start, int end){
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public int compareTo(Range range) {
        if(this.start<range.start) return -1;
        if(this.start>range.start) return 1;
        if(this.start==range.start){
            if(this.end<range.end) return -1;
            if(this.end>range.end) return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    //... getters for fields
}
```

---

```
public class RangeBianrySearch{

    public static Range findRangeFor(int value, List<Range> rangeList) {
        return findRange(value, rangeList, 0, rangeList.size()-1);
    }

    private static Range findRangeFor(int value, List<Range> rangeList, int start, int end) {

        if(end<0 || start==rangeList.size()) return null;

        int index;
        index = start+(end-start)/2;    
        Range range = rangeList.get(index);

        if(start!=end){
            if(range.getStart()>value){
                return findRangeFor(value, rangeList, start, index-1);
            }else
            if(range.getEnd()<value){
                return findRangeFor(value, rangeList, index+1, end);
            }
        }

        if(range.getStart()<=value && range.getEnd()>=value){
            return range;
        }
        return null;
    }  
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Range> rangeList = new ArrayList<Range>();
rangeList.add(new Range(1,100));
rangeList.add(new Range(101,200));
rangeList.add(new Range(250,301));
//etc...
Collection.sort(rangeList); //important

Range range = RangeBianrySearch.findRangeFor(115);
```